# If $\dim X=\infty$, can there be a compact $C$ such that $X\setminus C$ has two components?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, normed-spaces, connectedness

Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional normed space. Can there be a compact $C$ such that $X\setminus C$ has two components?

My guess is no because compact sets are kind of "small" (their interiors are empty). But how can we prove it?

Comment: You should probably say something about the topology you're using when considering compactness.

Comment: @cmk it's just the norm topology

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "no". In fact, $X \setminus C$ is homeomorphic to $X$. See for example Corollary 5.1 in

Bessaga, Czesław, and Aleksander Pełczyński. Selected topics in infinite-dimensional topology. Vol. 58. Panstwowe wyd. naukowe, 1975.

Comment: Can you provide the chapter in which you found this corollary? Edit: I found it it's chapter 3.

Comment: @AdamChalumeau Sorry that I forgot to mention the chapter ;-)